# mongo-cxx-driver doubles to json

Tags: mongodb, c++11, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

While experimenting with the C++11 driver of MongoDB (version 3.1.0-rc0) the output of the following piece of code confused me.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

int main() {
  bsoncxx::builder::stream::document s;
  s << "x" << 1.0;

  std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(s) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{ "x" : 1 }
```

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. How can I make sure that BSON doubles are represented as floating point numbers in JSON?

**Configuration:** CentOS 7, gcc 6.2.0, mongo-c-driver 1.5.0, mongo-cxx-driver 3.1.0-rc0

Comment: What platform/architecture/compiler are you using? What version of libbson do you have?

Comment: When I run your code, I get `{ "x" : 1, "y" : 0.999999, "z" : 0.9999999 }` all on one line.  (3.1.0-rc0 and libbson 1.5.0 on darwin)

Comment: You're right - I should have mentioned that. I updated my question. BTW, I did not install libbson explicitly, I think it came with the mongo-c-driver.

Comment: And is your actually output multi-line?  Or single-line?

Comment: I am sorry - there appears to have been an issue with my CMake project - if I run this code in a stand-alone setting the output is the same as yours, sorry about that. Nonetheless, questions 1) and 2) remain. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that behavior is inherent to libbson, which provides the JSON serialization.  It's sort of technically correct, since Javascript doesn't distinguish numeric types, but I understand how you'd prefer it to keep the decimal component, even if 0.

So at the moment, the answer to your questions are

1. Not expected, but not surprising.
2. At the moment, you can't do that from mongocxx.  You could iterate the BSON structure and construct a JSON document with another JSON library.

I'll take up the issue with the libbson maintainers as well.  (Update: Filed ticket [CDRIVER-1945](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-1945)).

Comment: Thank you! The conversion to integer becomes a problem when reading that value again and you expect it to still be a double. That's why I think this behavior can be problematic.

Comment: Generally, you can't rely on JSON values having the same type unless you're absolutely sure consumers/producers are doing/expecting the same thing.  MongoDB created ["extended JSON"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) to preserve type info when reading/writing JSON.  The bsoncxx library doesn't provide that yet, but will be sometime in 2017.  Some of the other language drivers already do.

Comment: I still think it is inconsistent if a number which is a double is converted to an integer depending on its value. When I convert `1.000000000000001` to JSON and save it to the database later, I expect it to be a double, no?

Comment: I understand.  But the "J" in JSON is "Javascript" which isn't a statically typed language and has a very sloppy "number" type anyway.  So JSON is just a terrible interchange format if you care about types.

Comment: I see - I would highly appreciate it if the `libbson` project from MongoDB would keep the floating point since it a) makes life easier for languages like c++ and b) does not make a difference to Javascript anyway. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Please feel free to vote on the [CDRIVER-1945](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-1945) ticket or add a comment explaining why it's important to you.